# Linux command executing

Tags: linux, command

hello Guys I need help.
I Have a file content ip and subdomains for a scope.
content file is:

```
trainingstg.linuxfoundation.org |
151.101.1.5
151.101.129.5
151.101.65.5
trainingstatus.linuxfoundation.org |
18.234.32.150
18.234.32.149
52.215.192.133
gerrit.linuxfoundation.org |
34.211.181.97
52.26.94.230
52.89.66.106
```

I need just subdomain not ip, so I want command i linux Gut ip without subdomains
What I can do?
the file name is subdomains.txt

Comment: You gave sample input - good. You didn't give sample output - not so good.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you also can use the below commands  to filter  your file with **sed**:

**This one will delete  all the  ips directly  in the  file**

```
sed -i '/^[0-9]/d' subdomains.txt
```

**ouput**

trainingstg.linuxfoundation.org |

trainingstatus.linuxfoundation.org |

gerrit.linuxfoundation.org |

**This other one will also get rid  of the character "|" and leave only the  domains but the output is not written to  the file directly**

```
sed -e '/^[0-9]/d' -e 's/|//g' subdomains.txt
```

**output**

trainingstg.linuxfoundation.org

trainingstatus.linuxfoundation.org

gerrit.linuxfoundation.org

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your file content with `egrep` to print only the lines that contain alphabet letters AND eventually numbers, if you want full compatibility, but not ONLY numbers, like:

```
$ egrep '([a-<][0-9][a-z]|[a-z][0-9])' file
trainingstg.linuxfoundation.org |
trainingstatus.linuxfoundation.org |
gerrit.linuxfoundation.org |
```